# How to render a different background image based on screen width?

Tags: css

I have the following markup, and I need to set two different background images at different breakpoints.

```
<body>
   <main>
      <div class="intro" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_mobile_image);"></div>
      <section>
        ....
      </section>
      <section>
        ....
      </section>
  </main>
</body>
```

I can only set the background image in the `style` attribute in the HTML markup. How can I render a background image suitable for mobile and a different image that is suitable for desktop?

Should I have two different divs like this setting `intro-mobile` to display none on a desktop breakpoint and setting `intro-desktop` to display none on a mobile breakpoint?

```
  <div class="intro intro-mobile" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_mobile_image);"></div>
  <div class="intro intro-desktop" style="background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_desktop_image);"></div>
```

Comment: Please write a comment before voting my question down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [CSS media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).

For example (assuming you want to show mobile background on screens < 768px wide).

```css
.intro {
    background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_mobile_image);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .intro {
        background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_desktop_image);
    }
}
```

Or if you need to have it inside of the style attribute, you could use media queries to hide the other div.

```css
.intro-desktop {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .intro-desktop {
        display: block;
    }

    .intro-mobile {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

---

Also, if you can include a `<style>` inside of the markup, you could just do:

```html
<style>
.intro {
    background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_mobile_image);
}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {
    .intro {
        background-image: url(https://s3.amazonaws.com/my_desktop_image);
    }
}
</style>
```

Comment: Because I could not have the image source in my stylesheet and I only could have the image source of my background image on the `div` in the HTML markup, I had to use your suggestion that suggests using media queries. In other words, I have to duplicate my HTML markup and have one div with `intro-mobile` and another with `intro-desktop` and toggle there display from `none` to `flex` depending on the set breakpoint. I am not too sure if this is best practice -- but this is the only way I could achieve my goal.

Comment: @robskrob One of my suggestions should surely work, if you can't do the first one, third one would be better over the second one.

Comment: Yes, Mat Sz, I believe I said your second suggestion worked for me. Thank you for your answer. In fact I believe I checked your answer as the accepted answer.